# IP Address not found on route 53 domain

Tags: amazon-web-services, error-handling, amazon-route53

I'm starting out on AWS and try to host a website on the platform. The S3 bucket and its content is set up and i'm able to access the website via the url s3 is providing.

Permissions and properties are set to accept public traffic and that the bucket is used to host a website. The index document is correct.

Now i want traffic to be redirected to my domain visionranger.com, but it shows the error "IP address could not be found"

I tested this issue on 4 different devices across multiple browsers (including Chrome, Safari and Firefox).

Bucket, domain and hosted zone do have the same name and as AWS recommends, I asked my previous provider if they transferred the dns services to the new provides (in this case route 53) and they did.

I waited longer than 48 hours after settings everything up before writing this so all services should be working by now - but they don't.

The image shows the dns records of route 53.

I am grateful for any help.

[image]

Comment: Did you buy the domain in Route 53 or was this domain brought elsewhere?

Comment: it was bought through one.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By running a DIG command to get the `NS` value of your domain it returns a `SERVFAIL` indicating that the configured nameservers for your domain do not contain the record for you domain.

The next step is to run a `whois` which indicates your configured nameservers are below:

- NS1.BDM.MICROSOFTONLINE.COM
- NS2.BDM.MICROSOFTONLINE.COM
- NS3.BDM.MICROSOFTONLINE.COM
- NS4.BDM.MICROSOFTONLINE.COM

As you're trying to use a Route 53 public hosted zone you will need to update your domain registrar to use the nameservers found under the `NS` record of the public hosted zone.

Follow the instructions [here](https://help.one.com/hc/en-us/articles/360000841638-How-do-I-change-the-name-servers-) for your specific domain.

Comment: thank you very much for that info. I had no clue that these records are still specified. that explains it. The problem is, that i cannot change my nameserver entries in one.com. I have contacted microsoft and let's see what is going on there. Thank you very much.

Comment: No problem have a great dya :)